# Is a solid slab of rolled steel the strongest form?

Tags: material-science

**Is a solid slab of rolled steel its strongest form?**

**Or can it be made stronger, in another form (layered, foam, mesh, braided etc)?**

(Its weight is not a factor, and no alloys/additives)

**Also, would the answer apply to other materials as well, or only rolled steel/metal?**

Comment: Steel is not pure iron, so you have already violated the no “alloy/additive” rule.

Comment: When you look at steel structures, do you only see slabs?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a billet of steel in its raw, hot-rolled form, this is not its strongest state, for the following reasons.

The processing steps which follow the creation of a hot-rolled steel billet (that turn it into useful shapes like beams, bars, sheets and wire) will alter its mechanical properties and thereby affect its strength. For example, the action of drawing a bar of steel through a series of progressively smaller dies will eventually turn that bar into a very long piece of wire. If the drawing process is performed without heating the wire, then the steel will be *cold-worked* into a significantly harder and stronger state than it was in as a hot-rolled billet.

Furthermore, if the steel billet contains alloying agents like chrome, vanadium, molybdenum, etc. then it is also possible to apply *heat treatment* steps in combination with *cold work* to make the steel significantly stronger than it was in its raw form.

Finally, note that a billet of hot-rolled steel often contains slag inclusions which compromise its strength. In the process of forming smaller parts out of that billet, the inclusions are discovered and removed, which makes the finished parts more robust than the raw billet.